# Help with computing eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If we know that $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ symmetric matrix, and we have eigenvalue $\lambda_1 = 0$ with eigenvector $a=(0,0,1)$, eigenvalue $\lambda_2=1$ with eigenvector $b=(2,1,0)$, and $\lambda_3 < 0$, how to find a solution to $Ax=b$?

Comment: "Third eigenvector is negative."  Do you mean the third eigenvalue?

Comment: yes you are right, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $b$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $1$, so we have:
$$Ab=1b=b$$
Thus, $x=b$ is a solution. Now, any solution other than $x=b$ must differ by $b$ by an element of the null space. We know that $\lambda_1=0$ with eigenvector $a$, so the null space is $ca$ for $c \in \Bbb{R}$. Thus, our possible solutions are:
$$x=b+ca \text{ for } c \in \Bbb{R}$$

Comment: thanks Noble, shouldn't I need to calculate A matrix?

Comment: @tanja If we're just solving for $x$, then we don't need to calculate what $A$ is. However, there is enough information to solve for $A$ and I can do it if you want me to.

Comment: Well I tried to solve it by my self, but I think I am getting wrong answer. My matrix is A11= (2-k)/2; A12=k; A13=0; A21=k; A22=1-2k, and all others are zero.

Comment: @tanja What was your answer? I also solved for $A$, but I think I got the wrong answer because I'm getting $\lambda_3=1$: $$A=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right]$$

Comment: My matrix is A11= (2-k)/2; A12=k; A13=0; A21=k; A22=1-2k, and all others are zero.

Comment: @tanja Thanks! I know what I did wrong know: I said $A_{11}=A_{22}$ even though that is not true. If we calculate the trace of this matrix, we get: $$\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3=A_{11}+A_{22}+A_{33}$$ $$0+1+\lambda_3=\frac{2-k}{2}+(1-2k)+0$$ $$\lambda_3=\frac{2-5k}{2}$$ However, there are still an infinite number of possible $k$ where $\lambda_3 < 0$, so I don't know what the answer here would be...Sorry!

Comment: I think you should ask a separate question asking someone else to solve for $A$.

Comment: that is ok, you help me a lot with this solution. I didn't remember this formula λ1+λ2+λ3=A11+A22+A33. Thank you